# SQL Server join difficulties

Tags: sql-server

I have difficulties to achieve the following task:

I have 2 SQL Server tables: ImportLog and TShipping.

My application insert lot of  row (for example 10 rows) in TShipping table

```
 TShipping(TShipping_ID int, TShipping_CreationDate datetime)
```

and than (at the end of the process, i.e. after few millisecond), insert 1 row
into ImportLog  table

```
 ImportLog(ImportLog_Date datetime, importlog_Nb int).
```

In TShipping table I have one more field:

```
importlog_Nb int
```

I want to update this field (importlog_Nb of TShipping table, i.e. TShipping.importlog_Nb) with the value of importlog_Nb of importlog table (i.e. importlog.importlog_Nb)

So the difficulty is to find, for each row in TShipping table, the row in importlog table having the nearest ImportLog_Date to TShipping_CreationDate (nearest i.e. >= not <= because importlog table is filled after TShipping table).

Remarque: for each time the process run, it insert lot of rows in TShipping table and only 1 row in ImportLog table.

If anyone can give me a simple code without using cursor (because TShipping table is enormous).

create table TShipping (TShipping_ID int TShipping_CreationDate datetime, ImportLog_Nb int)

create table ImportLog (ImportLog_Date datetime, ImportLog_Nb int)

Comment: A SQL Fiddle would be nice.

Comment: Or just a bit of formatting...

Comment: Show the `CREATE TABLE` statements here for the applicable tables if you want a quick and useful answer.

Comment: Why not just create a local datetime variable as part of your initial batch and use that variable for the second insert?

Comment: is ImportLog.importlog_Nb an identity field? if so, insert the ImportLog record first and then retrieve it using an output clause and then when you insert all of the TShipping records, you can just put it in directly.

Comment: Cardiak, I just added this new field (ImportLog_Nb) today in TShipping Table and I need to fill it for the entire rows of TShipping table

Comment: No ImportLog_Nb contain an integer Nb (not an identity field)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t
    set t.importlog_Nb = i.importlog_Nb
FROM TShipping t
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 i.importlog_Nb, i.ImportLog_Date 
    FROM ImportLog i
    WHERE i.ImportLog_Date >= t.TShipping_CreationDate
    ORDER BY i.ImportLog_Date ASC
) i
```

This pulls the nearest import log date after shipping and assigns it